# Chrome `navigator.onLine` is incorrectly false

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm in a regular Chrome browser. I am using a third party library - firebase to do authentication. I kept getting these errors:

```
auth/network-request-failed
A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
```

Finally, with the help of firebase support, figured out that this is the issue:

- the firebase SDK checks `navigator.onLine` before sending the request to authenticate (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/auth/src/utils.js#L1176)

In my Chrome browser, `navigator.onLine` is always `false`. This happens:

- On every website I go to, in every tab
- With every Chrome user profile that I have
- Without any Chrome extensions
- In an incognito tab

Chrome info (latest):

- Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)

In other browsers, both Safari and Firefox `navigator.onLine` is correctly `true`.

Is `navigator.onLine` reliable? Or it it known to be buggy, or is something else going on? I searched Chromium bugs to get a better idea but couldn't find any clues https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=navigator.online

Comment: so, that's a problem you have with your Chrome - not a programming question at all

Comment: Fair point, but consider this: if `navigator.onLine` is known to be unreliable, then the programming question is that libraries should not use `navigator.onLine`, if this is the case I can submit a PR to the firebase library to do a better job at detecting online without the use of `navigator.onLine`

Comment: Sure - have you checked Chrome dev pages to see if it's a "known issue" for "some" ... because that's where I'd be headed, rather than trying to get libraries changed just because Chrome sux :p

Comment: Yep, I couldn't find anything suspicious recently reported in Chrome https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=navigator.online

Comment: have you tried downgrading to Chrome 61? I ask, because so many things seem to be broken in 62!

Comment: its working fine on my chrome `Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)`. so far no delays.

Comment: I have been having issues with this being false sometimes in my cordova app on android. I've tried so many different things to fix it. I'm about ready to override navigator.onLine to just always return true.

Comment: @Treyphor I also almost did that, but the issue happens rarely so I haven't yet reached that point. If possible, can you add any debugging details to the chromium ticket? Maybe it would help get to the bottom of the issue.

Answer (score 4):

It's a known bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=navigator.online

Try using `online` and `offline` events instead. See the workaround from Vercel SWR: https://github.com/vercel/swr/blob/main/_internal/src/utils/web-preset.ts

Comment: Is there an updated URL for the workaround?